# CKEditor Source Code Mode Copy

Tags: ckeditor, orchardcms, clipboard

*Any other suggestions?*

When using CKEditor copying from one instance to another (with CTRL+C/V). You always get some changed source code. Even with Advanced Content Filtering enabled and only allowing a few plugins and content rules.

Check this example here (Code 1):

```
<p>nubosys GmbH ist ein 
Infrastrukturanbieter und bietet für eine moderne Informations- und 
Kommunikationstechnologie (ICT) das ideale Umfeld.<p>
```

CTRL+C/V in another instance becomes this (Code 2):

```
<p><span>nubosys</span> GmbH ist ein Infrastrukturanbieter und bietet 
für eine moderne <span>Informations</span>- 
und  Kommunikationstechnologie (ICT) das ideale Umfeld.</p>
```

So what you see is that unnecessary **span** tags get inserted

When I monitor the clipboard I see this (Code 3):

[image: original clipboard contents]

So you see CKEditor does quit a good job filtering out things. But it is not 100% the same as in the original.

My approach would be to implement a source code based copy mode. So I am wondering if something like this does not exist already for CKEditor. My use case is to copy from one instance to another instance of the editor inside the CMS.

I case you want more background information. Here is the CKEditor Plugin for Orchard CMS we started: https://github.com/inteno/CustomCK/wiki/Introduction

**How to force the user to copy the HTML Code from one instance to another (without source changes) with one click or by pressing CTRL+C/V.**

When I use forcePasteAsPlainText: true, the problem does not occur, but the formatting is lost. I want a clean way to copy the formatting without changing the source.

**Update:**

In this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mjost/6rgo0udg/15/ the problem does not occur. CKEditor manages to filter out the bad code:

```
Version:0.9
StartHTML:0000000165
EndHTML:0000000886
StartFragment:0000000201
EndFragment:0000000850
SourceURL:http://fiddle.jshell.net/mjost/6rgo0udg/15/show/
<html>
<body>
<!--StartFragment--><p style="box-sizing: border-box; border-radius: 0px !important; margin: 0px 0px 10px; color: rgb(85, 85, 85); font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; letter-spacing: normal; line-height: 20.7999992370605px; orphans: auto; text-align: start; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; white-space: normal; widows: 1; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px;">nubosys GmbH ist ein Infrastrukturanbieter und bietet fÃ¼r eine moderne Informations- und Kommunikationstechnologie (ICT) das ideale Umfeld.</p><br class="Apple-interchange-newline"><!--EndFragment-->
</body>
</html>
```

(http://freeclipboardviewer.com/)

But that is because there are no spans even in the clipboard.

**Update 2:**

The problem occurs here when I work with none breaking spaces:

http://jsfiddle.net/mjost/r34c7fLe/5/

HTML

```
<body>
        <textarea id="cke1"><p>nubosys GmbH wurde 2011 von inteno ag und&nbsp;edicomp&nbsp;GmbH&nbsp;gegr&uuml;ndet. nubosys GmbH ist ein Infrastrukturanbieter und bietet f&uuml;r eine moderne Informations- und Kommunikationstechnologie (ICT) das ideale Umfeld.</p>
    </textarea>

            <textarea id="cke2"></textarea>
    </body>
```

JS

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'cke1', {
    forcePasteAsPlainText: false,
     extraAllowedContent: 'span;'
} );
CKEDITOR.replace( 'cke2', {
    forcePasteAsPlainText: false,
     extraAllowedContent: 'span;'
} );
```

**Updated Question:**

According to the latest experiments I think it should be a Plugin that overwrites the default Copy&Paste and works on a Source Code base. Is this possible?

Comment: Using Chrome browser?

Comment: And in other browsers?

Comment: I have tested in IE and Firefox and Chrome. And it seems this issue is specific to chrome/Webkit. If I monitor the clipboard with IE, the HTML gets worse. But luckily no addtional spans. So I am really looking for a 1:1 copy of the source. everything else always could cause that some new tags get instered (especially when I need them in other cases).

Comment: to see the contents of the clipboard: http://freeclipboardviewer.com/

Comment: Seems a webkit issue: http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor/ckeditor-4.01-inserting-span-elements-everywhere-with-a-line-height-of-1.6em

Comment: But I am not sure if it is since other browser produce also crap code when copying. So I am looking for a safe source code copy mode.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be some incompatibility between CKEditor and Chrome/Webkit. I'm not sure if you have any specific reason for that javascript. But `forcePasteAsPlainText: false` is redundant because that's default value. And `extraAllowedContent: 'span;'` is what's causing your problem with inserted spans.

If you don't need to set more options you can remove all javascript and just use `class="ckeditor"` on textareas to load editors on them.

Another way is to hit **Source** button on CKEditor's toolbar and copy the source directly, that is always 1:1 then you can hit **Source** button on second CKEditor and paste it there, again 1:1.

Does it still bug for you in this fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/tfoaw743/1/

Comment: To your first assumption. Yes I know it is just for clarification that I am aware of the setting. extraAllowedContent is something that I need.

Comment: Thank you for the hint with class. Regarding your description with source. I know this. I am thinking about a plugin which does this automatically. What do you think. So that normal users are forced to copy on a source mode base.

Comment: No it does not occur. But it is not a solution for me since I want to allow span in general.

Comment: I am looking for an approach which is as easy as copy paste and copies the source. So I could think of a plugin which overwrites the default copy paste behaviour. I think the normal clipboard mechanism will never work 100% if you see what chrome or IE produces.